Connect Multiple Stripe account in Flutter App
I'm building a Flutter app to sell products. The app will list products in multiple currencies at the same time, and I have two Stripe accounts to accept payments.
For example: product 1 in USD and product 2 in Euros.
Product 1 will accept payment in Stripe 1, and product 2 will accept payment in Stripe account 2.
I'm struggling to initialize Stripe for two accounts at the same time. Is there any way I can do that? Thanks in advance.
I try initializing 2 publisher key in main function. Initially no error maybe overriding previous one.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It's possible to use the same Stripe account to accept payments in different currencies: https://docs.stripe.com/currencies
Stripe recommends using different accounts only if there are different legal entities involved or if you need to pay out to different external bank accounts: https://docs.stripe.com/get-started/account/multiple-accounts
If you need to use two accounts here, it may be simpler to ask a customer early on in the checkout flow to select a country, and then only present the products associated with the Stripe account you want to use for customers in that country.
